# Alamofire on travis with Swift 5.1

Tags: alamofire, travis-ci

I'm trying to run my project with Travis but I can't compile because of an issue with Alamofire. It is not clear to me why it is not working... I'm using alamofire version 4.8 and it should support Xcode 11 and Swift 5.1 without any issue (also, I can compile and run the app locally with Xcode 11.2, the only issue I have is trying to compile it with travis)

This is the error message I see on Travis

```
module compiled with Swift 5.0.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1 compiler: /Users/travis/build/MyUser/app-ios/app-ios/Carthage/Build/iOS/Alamofire.framework/Modules/Alamofire.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule
```

This is my current configuration:

```
osx_image: xcode11
language: swift
branches:
  only:
    - master
script: xcodebuild test -workspace apps.xcworkspace -scheme Travis -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,OS=13.0' | xcpretty && exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

I've also tried to use Xcode 11.2 and a simulator with ios 13.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to recompile your Carthage dependencies using something like `carthage update --no-use-binaries --platform iOS`.

Comment: Why using --no-use-binaries? I've already updated the libraries, the project correctly compiles locally. The issue is that it doesn't not compile on travis.